# Remove Disqus JavaScript from homepage

Tags: functions, homepage, disqus

Hey WordPress friends,

I’m using the Disqus comment system plugin, which is working fine. My homepage is just a collection if recent posts and therefore not having the option to leave a comment (as desired).

Unfortunately, I still see that the Disqus plugin is rendering JavaScript output within the homepage and would like to get rid of this.

I've Tried the following but without luck. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

```
function block_disqus_count() {
if ( is_front_page())
    remove_filter('output_count_js', 'dsq_output_count_js');
}

add_action( 'block_disqus_count' , 'block_disqus_count');
```

Comment: Plugins are off-topic here... lo ciento mi amigo.

Comment: Hi Kevin, welcome to WPSE. As @jgraup says - you'll need to ask this at the Disqus forums, sorry!

Comment: That's fine. It can be seen as a general WP programming question. I 'm just trying to overwrite / suppress the call of a plugin, which isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You should deregister it. Add this function into your functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disqus_scripts' );

function disqus_scripts() {
  if(is_front_page()) {
    wp_deregister_script('disqus_count');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by altering the file disqus.php. First find function

```
function dsq_output_count_js() {
```

Add the following check before the function tries to output the JS

```
 if ( ! is_front_page() ) { ?> <script type="text/javascript">
```

I’m using this until Disqus created the option to configure this. Thanks for the help.